# schema does not exist error with Postgresql and Texticle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I tried to configure [Texticle](http://tenderlove.github.com/texticle/) and ran into this error on migration. Error msg is referring to the line I marked with <<<<

```
PGError: ERROR:  schema "half_links" does not exist
:       CREATE VIEW searches AS
    SELECT items.id AS searchable_id, items.name AS term,
      CAST('Item' AS varchar) AS searchable_type
    FROM items
    UNION
    SELECT half_links.id AS searchable_id, half_links.item.name AS term,     <<<<
      CAST('HalfLink' AS varchar) AS searchable_type
    FROM half_links
```

This is my migration

```
class CreateSearches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL
    CREATE VIEW searches AS
     SELECT items.id AS searchable_id, items.name AS term,
       CAST('Item' AS varchar) AS searchable_type
     FROM items
     UNION
     SELECT half_links.id AS searchable_id, half_links.item.name AS term,
       CAST('HalfLink' AS varchar) AS searchable_type
     FROM half_links
   SQL
 end
```

and models

```
:half_link belongs_to :item
:item has_many :half_links
```

Im running this on my localhost PSQL. How can I get around this?

Comment: what do you mean by `half_links.item.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the second select. `half_links.item.name` makes Postgres assume that half_links is a schema name (the correct syntax is ..)

Seeing how your associations are, I guess you mean to get the name of the items belonging to half_links.

Since Postgres have no idea on how the Rails associations works, you need to get the data yourself:

```
CREATE VIEW searches AS
     SELECT items.id AS searchable_id, items.name AS term,
       CAST('Item' AS varchar) AS searchable_type
     FROM items
     UNION
     SELECT half_links.id AS searchable_id, items.name AS term,
       CAST('HalfLink' AS varchar) AS searchable_type
     FROM half_links join items on half_links.item_id = items.id
```

This is assuming that the foreign key in `half_links` to `items` are called `item_id` which it should be if you created the tables using Rails migration.

Additionally, this will only show the half_links that actually have an item associated to it, if there can be ones that don't have an item, then change the `join` to `outer join`. Term will in those cases be NULL.